# How to resolve NullPointerException error while implementing POM with cucumber framework

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, cucumber, maven, pom

I am getting java.lang.NullPointerException while executing my test case, I am using Page Object Modle with cucumber framework in my maven project, following are the code snippets
**BoxJunitScript.java**

```
package com.stepDefinition;

public class BoxJunitScipt {
     WebDriver driver;
     WebDriverWait wait;
     LoginPage lp;
     AllFilesPage afp;


 static DriverInstance instance;

    {
        instance = DriverInstance.getinstance();
        driver = instance.getDiver();
        wait = instance.getWait();

    }

 @Before    
 public void setUp() {

        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        lp = new LoginPage(driver);
        afp = new AllFilesPage(driver);
 }




 @Given("user navigates to App box page")
 public void user_navigates_to_App_box_page() {

     driver.manage().window().maximize();
     driver.get("https://app.box.com"); 
     lp.pageVerify();

 }

 @When("user enters username and password given below")
 public void user_enters_username_and_password_given_below(DataTable loginData) {

     List<List<String>> loginData1 = loginData.asLists();  //convert data in list
       for(List<String> row: loginData1) {
           String email = row.get(0);
           String password = row.get(1);
           lp.loginIntoApp(email,password);
       }
 }

 @Then("page with title {string} should open")
 public void page_with_title_should_open(String title) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
     afp.pageVerify(title);

 }

 @When("user clicks on LogOut")
 public void user_clicks_on_LogOut() {
     afp.logoutFromApp();
     driver.quit();
 }
}
```

**LoginPage.java**

```
package com.stepDefinition;

import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.AjaxElementLocatorFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class LoginPage  {

private WebDriver driver;
WebDriverWait wait;


@FindBy(how=How.NAME, using="login")
WebElement emailTextField;
@FindBy(how=How.CSS, using="button[id='login-submit']")
 WebElement nextButton;
@FindBy(how=How.NAME, using="password")
WebElement passwordTextField;
@FindBy(css="button[id='login-submit-password']")
WebElement logInButton;

public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
    AjaxElementLocatorFactory ajaxDriver = new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(driver, 45);
    PageFactory.initElements(ajaxDriver, LoginPage.class);
}

public void loginIntoApp(String username, String password) {
    emailTextField.sendKeys(username);
    nextButton.click();
    passwordTextField.sendKeys(password);
    logInButton.click();

}

public void pageVerify() {

    System.out.println("Before getting title");
    String title = driver.getTitle();
    System.out.println("After getting title");

    if(title.equals("Box | Login")) 
        System.out.println("Page title is correct");
}

public static void waitUntil(WebElement element, WebDriver driver) {
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
            .ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class)
            .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
}
}
```

**AllFilePage.java**

```
package com.stepDefinition;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.AjaxElementLocatorFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;


public class AllFilesPage {

WebDriver driver;
 WebDriverWait wait;


@FindBy(css="button[data-resin-target='accountmenu']")
WebElement toggleAccountMenu;
@FindBy(css="a[data-resin-target='logout']")
WebElement logOutlink;

public AllFilesPage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        AjaxElementLocatorFactory ajaxDriver = new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(driver, 45);
        PageFactory.initElements(ajaxDriver, AllFilesPage.class);
}

public void logoutFromApp() {
    toggleAccountMenu.click();
    logOutlink.click();
}

public void pageVerify(String title) {
    String Actualtitle = driver.getTitle();
    if(Actualtitle.equals(title)) {
        System.out.println("Page title is correct123");

    } else {
        System.err.println("Page title is not correct");
        }
}

}
```

**CreateInstance.java**

```
package com.stepDefinition;

import com.driver.DriverInstance;

import io.cucumber.core.api.Scenario;
import io.cucumber.java.After;
import io.cucumber.java.Before;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;


public class CreateInstance {

    public static String browserName = null;

@Given("Browser is {string}")
public void browsere_is(String browser) {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    if(browserName == null) {
        DriverInstance.setInstance(browser);
        browserName = browser;
    }
    if(browserName!= null && !browserName.equals(browser)) {
        DriverInstance.setInstance(browser);
        browserName = browser;
    }
}

@Before
public void beforeScenario(Scenario sc) {
    System.out.println(sc.getName());
    System.out.println("Runs before all");
}

@After
public void afterScenario(Scenario sc) {
    System.out.println(sc.getStatus());
}
}
```

**DriverInstance.java**

```
package com.driver;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class DriverInstance {

public static DriverInstance instance;
WebDriver driver;
WebDriverWait wait;

public DriverInstance(String browser) {
    if(browser.equals("firefox")) {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }
    else if(browser.equals("chrome")) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\selenium-server\\Driver\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
}

public static void setInstance(String browser) {
    DriverInstance.instance = new DriverInstance(browser);
}

public static DriverInstance getinstance() {
    return instance;
}

public WebDriver getDiver() {
    return driver;
}

public WebDriverWait getWait() {
    return wait;
}
}
```

I am getting this error on line  **lp.pageVerify()** in **BoxJunitScript.java** and when i debug my code i observed that i am getting null value for **lp** object after this line **lp = new LoginPage(driver)** in **BoxJunitScript.java**

Comment: maybe coz you are using the Driver as private in LoginPage.

Comment: ` lp = new LoginPage(driver);
            lp.pageVerify();` will work

Comment: I'm not sure whether 'setup method' is executed or not. can you debug that using some print statement over there ?

Comment: @NarendraR after debugging I observed that setup method is not getting executed and when I initialize LoginPage object lp before the statement lp.pageVerify it worked, but it throws another null pointer exception to the statement where I am calling again the method of login page i.e. lp.loginIntoApp(email, password); and in line emailTextField.sendKeys(username); of LoginPage.java

Comment: @UpdeshKumar this solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: _setup method is not getting executed_ is causing this error. either you need to debug and make this working or write setup method code in static block.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that you have provided a proper code or you have right understanding of where your exception appears.

As per your code:

```
{
    instance = DriverInstance.getinstance();
    driver = instance.getDiver();
    wait = instance.getWait();
}
```

you get a reference to a static field `instance = DriverInstance.getinstance();` that is basically you can read as `static DriverInstance instance = DriverInstance.getinstance();`

So after this line you do not have an object. Thus calling `driver = instance.getDiver();` should cause NPE.

You never create an instance of your `DriverInstance` because the instance can be created in two ways.

1. Calling constructor `public DriverInstance(String browser)`
2. Calling static method `public static void setInstance(String browser)`

So I believe you need to reconsider your architecture and use `static` things only where they are really improve your experience.